# Error playing video from snapchat (.mp4)

Tags: codec

I have a video from snapchat that I have difficulties playing (on the computer).

It's a .mp4 and it plays perfectly on VLC and QuickTime - but not on anything else. I've tried downloading all sorts of codecs and stuff but i dont get it to work. It dosen't work when uploaded to youtube or facebook for example.

Often the first images are fine, but then the rest of the video is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW3kl.png

It can also be the reversed. The first images dont show but the rest of the video is fine.

This is the video (for download): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2hzopfx_ybFLWpVMmJyTnctLUU

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that Snapchat allows to select multiple clips of different parameters and stitch them together as one MP4.

Like you said, it plays fine in VLC, but ffplay here warns that

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000005b0a00] Concatenated H.264 or
> H.265 might not play correctly.
>
> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @> 00000000005ba100] ignoring multiple glbl
>
> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @> 00000000005b0a00] multiple edit list entries, a/v desync might occur, patch welcome

VLC fails to convert to a good file. Crude method would to screen-record the video playback and crop that, or Snapchat seems to allow to download the individual clips, which would be the best possible method for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mac, it's possible to import it into iMovie, then reexport it. The resulting exported .mp4 will then be usable on YouTube (and I assume others).